# Mesh collider doesnt follow the body

Tags: unity-game-engine, model, mesh, collider

I created very simple leg model in blender and added some bones. In unity when im tryng to move bones, the mesh collider stays in the same position. [screen model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V82Uw.png)

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Unity does not have a real native support for moving mesh colliders to align with a mesh. This is mostly due to the **very high performance cost** of having to recreate it to match up with the mesh every frame (it is technically possible, but runs very slow).

Simulations and games that require collision on a ragdoll or bone structure (like the leg in the picture) will just use **primitives** as colliders instead since because they can be adjusted to give roughly the **same collision output as a mesh collider.**

**In your case, this could be circumvented by adding a capsule collider or box collider to each of the separate bones in the leg and then adjusting their dimensions to roughly fit the mesh.** The new primitive colliders you add should then follow it properly.

Here is a link to a similar question: [Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1197217/can-a-mesh-collider-work-with-an-animated-skinned.html)

Basically, if an object moves and needs collision, it is best to use primitives.

Comment: Understood. But what should I do if I need really accurate collider for one part of the body? I need that for foot, to determine the direction of the kick.

Comment: Assuming that the leg has 3 separate bones, using two capsule colliders for the leg bones and a box collider for the foot should be sufficiently accurate. After you tweak the sizes of each collider it should function close enough to as if it had a mesh collider in the first place.